# how to change text color in the middle of the sentence in android

Tags: android, string, colors

I need to change the color of the String which appears randomly in a sentence.

Ex: These following sentences are what I need to display.

1. hai **#xyz** how are you.
2. i am learning **#abc** android.

   In this I have to change the color of the words "**#xyz**", "**#abc**" i.e, which starts with the character "**#**".

   I used some string functions split(), subString(). but I am not getting what i need.

so, please guide me how to solve this.

Comment: you can use `Spannablestring`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use SpannableString for ex:

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("hai #xyz how are you.");
ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 4, 9, 0);
```

Try following to change color of each word with #:

```
String s="hai #xyz how are you.";
ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
String[] ss = s.split(" ");
int currIndex = 0;
for (String word : ss) {
    if (word.startsWith("#")) {
        ss.setSpan(span, currIndex,currIndex+ word.length(), 0);
    }
    currIndex += (word.length() + 1);
}
```

Comment: thank u,i find the # index value.But how to find the end positon,strings are differnt. ex:"hai #xyz how are you" and "hai how are you #venkat".

Comment: look for first space after #

Comment: can you suggest me how to get it ?

Answer (score 4):

you can use this code:

```
t.setText(first + next, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable s = (Spannable)t.getText();
int start = first.length();
int end = start + next.length();
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFFF0000), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

or you can use html:

```
String first = "This word is ";
String next = "<font color='#EE0000'>red</font>";
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(first + next));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily achieve this using html tags

```
tv_message.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#000000\">"+"Hi "+"</font>"+" "+"<font color=\"#EE0000\">"+"XYZ "+"</font>"+" "+"<font color=\"#000000\">"+"How are You ?  " + "</font>"));
```